# How to prepare domain on multifeature using Arcmap?

Tags: arcmap, esri-geodatabase, domains

I am using a Personal Geodatabase.  How do I set up domains on multiple fields?

Answer (score 4):

There is some good documentation on the ESRI Website for setting up Domains.  [**Here**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001s00000001000000.htm), [**here**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_new_attribute_range_domain/001s00000003000000/) and **[here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_new_coded_value_domain/001s00000004000000/)**.  See the links on the left of the page for even more detailed information.

Is there something more specific that you need help with that isn't in the ESRI help?